# execute Shell Commands From PL/SQL for copy file from a Network Drive

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle9i

my problem is that I have few 6i form which few of their task work with CMD and Batch file and I want to move my application to 10g. I am trying below code to use Java feature for copy files from one of network drive to other network drive(one of the batch file activity example) :
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/shell-commands-from-plsql.php

This example working fine for local drive and I can execute DIR command, move command ro MD command but when I am trying to connect to a Network drive it is not working

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000
CALL DBMS_JAVA.SET_OUTPUT(1000000);
BEGIN
    host_command (p_command => 'dir p:\temp\');
END;
```

Error:

> Process err :The system cannot find the path specified.

or

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000
CALL DBMS_JAVA.SET_OUTPUT(1000000);
BEGIN
    host_command (p_command => 'dir \\abcde-ef2\osbct01\DATA\Temp\');
END;
/
```

Error

> Process out : Volume in drive \abcde-ef2\osbct01 is osbct01 Process
>
> err :File Not Found Process out : Volume Serial Number is B4F6-A843
>
> Process out : Process out : Directory of
>
> \abcde-ef2\osbct01\DATA\Temp\ Process out :

Actually, I don't have any problem with `host_command ('dir c:\');` and I can see all the output, but when I change it to `host_command('dir p:\')` it cannot work. (`p` refer to a network location which map in my computer

Would you mind help me what is wrong that I cannot access to my *network* drives?

(p.s: I am not interested to use web_util in my oracle forms.)

Comment: I've edited your question to move some informations you provided in your comments. Could you review that -- and eventually fix the tags: it was tagged with [tag:oracle10g] but in your postscript you talked about [tag:oracle9i]. I left both of them -- but it is probably not required.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem related to operating system access privilege to "P:\"
you are trying to access P while OS prevent this because it is disconnected or protected with password or restricted users.

Comment: well I don't reject your idea, but I tried to run the same script in that PC, it is working fine. I remember for Microsoft SQL, I had a user in my PC but for Oracle it is not like that and there isn't any windows user for Oracle... I am using win server 2003.